# Perpetual functional of a Brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion

There exist some results concerning to the distribution of perpetual integral functionals of Brownian motion of the form $\int_0^\infty e^{−λs}f(B_s)\,\mathrm{d}s$, where $f$ is a nonnegative measurable function, $\{B_s:s\geq 0\}$ is a standard Brownian motion and $λ>0$ is a constant?